# Tikz: Translate between pt and unit measurements

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot a  indifference curve through a node `(b)` using gnuplot and tikz.
The relevant (though non-functional) part from my plot is

```
\draw
    let 
        \p1 = (b)
    in
        plot[domain=1:10] function{exp(log(\x1)-log(x)+log(\y1))};
```

Essentially, I want to access the `x` and `y` coordinate of point `(b)` separately, and use them in the function specification. The reason why it currently doesn't work is because the `let` function saves the coordinates in the latex `pt` unit, while the `plot` function plots according to my coordinate system.

I've tried many things, including computing the conversion myself using `veclen`, but that function returns the same unit as the input, and didn't get me any further. Surely there is something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please post a complete MWE? It wouldn't be bad if you could post a picture (with a external program or hand-drawn) how the output should look, too.

Comment: `\draw
    let 
        \p1 = (b),\n1={\y1*1cm/1pt},\n2={\x1*1cm/1pt}
    in
        plot[domain=1:10] function{exp(log(\n2)-log(x)+log(\n1))};` for your technical question or exploit the logarithm laws, `log(\x1)-log(\y1)=\log(\x1/\y1)` to see that the units cancel...

Comment: Isn't just `exp(log(\x1)-log(x)+log(\y1)) = \x1/x*\y1`?

Comment: @HenriMenke I agree with you but because of the usual sledge hammer concerns I hesitate to close the question because it is "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: @marmot The gold badge sledge hammer only enables you to single-handedly close as duplicate.  All other close votes still go through review.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! I didn't know that!

Comment: @marmot: The *1cm/1pt is genius! Thank you – I guess I didn't know what unit the default is. That solves my question – can you make your comment into an answer so I can officially mark it as resolved?

Comment: @ItsmeMimi Glad to hear that it worked. Your question has been closed, unfortunately, and I am partly responsible for that. As long as you got an answer that helps you, I think everything is fine. ;-)