# Basic TikZ "Missing number" error when using `asin` to calculate the end angle of arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

I am new to plotting in TikZ and has come across the "Missing number error" in the following example on the line marked by `%(**)`,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric,arrows,intersections} 
%shapes.geometric and arrows are used in other TikZ graphics not included in this MCVE
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\draw [name path=yaxis, ->,thick] (0,-2)--(0,12) node (yax) [above] {$\Im E$};
\draw [->,thick] (-20,0)--(12,0) node (xax) [right] {$\Re E$};
\path [name path=circular] (-15,0) arc (180:0:8);
\path [name intersections={of=circular and yaxis}];
\coordinate (c) at (intersection-1);
\draw [->,thick] let
    \p1=(c),
    \n1={\y1/8},              %(*)
    \n2={asin(\n1)}           %(**)
in (-15,0) arc (180:\n2:8);   %(***)
\draw let \p1=(c) in (0,\y1)--(7,\y1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have checked the existing questions on this site but has not yet found an answer, I tried adding braces in various ways around `%(*)` and `%(**)`, with no success. I also tried to merge the two `let`s into one like `\n1={asin(\y1/8)}`, and tried variations of this with braces added. All of them report missing numbers error. If I replace `\n1`in line `%(**)` with a number, or use `\n1` in place of `\n2` in `%(***)` (Not what I intended but I just want to check) there is also no errors.

Other observations,

- If I replace `acos` with `ln`, no error is reported
- If I replace `\y1/8` with `\y1`, the error "Dimension too large" is reported

#### Edit

`asin(\y1/8)=acos(7/8)`, so I can plot what I want anyway, but I just don't understand where the error comes from.

Comment: The error is due to the fact that you ask Ti*k*Z to take the arcsin of a number that is larger than 1. (There is an unrelated error in `\draw [name path=yaxis, ->,thick] (0,-2)--(0,12) node (yax) [above] {$\I`, which you seem to have forgotten to complete).

Comment: Fixed the $\I$ part, I tried changing `\y1/8` to `\y1/80` and got the same error, so I didn't think that was the reason. However, after you commented I double checked and now I believe you are correct.

Comment: (There is still a semicolon missing.) You can condense the relevant two lines to `\draw [->,thick] let  \p1=(c) in (-15,0) arc (180:{asin(\y1/8cm)}:8);  
\draw (c-|0,0) --  (c-|7,0);`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would compute the angle in a different way (assuming you do not want to do it analytically). You have a semicircle around `(-7,0)` of radius `8cm`, of which you want to draw the path to the intersection of the y-axis. That is, we want the polar coordinates of `(c)-(-7,0)`. The angle can be computed via `atan2`, which avoids having to divide by dimensions, and related errors that may occur when asking Ti*k*Z to compute the arcsin of a number larger than 1, as it occurs. `atan2` is defined for any arguments, so this error cannot occur (and this way of computing the angle is arguably more intuitive). The horizontal stretch does not require `calc` (but of course there is nothing wrong with using `calc` here).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\draw [name path=yaxis, ->,thick] (0,-2)--(0,12) node (yax) [above] {$\Im E$};
\draw [->,thick] (-20,0)--(12,0) node (xax) [right] {$\Re E$};
\path [name path=circular] (-15,0) arc (180:0:8);
\path [name intersections={of=circular and yaxis}];
\coordinate (c) at (intersection-1);
\draw [->,thick] let  \p1=($(c)-(-7,0)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in (-15,0) arc (180:\n1:8);  
\draw (c-|0,0) --  (c-|7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried `atan2` before I got the `cm` part. I had a number (without dimension) at where you put `\x1` and the result was not as expected. I guess I need to know about the `cm` before I can write correct code as above. Anyway, in the final version I used `acos(7/8)` and removed all the `let`s altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in a closed question. To me that question is very clear what is being asked and I don't know why it was closed.

Following the 2nd comment in [Tikz: Translate between pt and unit measurements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448198/tikz-translate-between-pt-and-unit-measurements), I changed `\n1={\y1/8}` to `\n1={\y1/8cm}`, and it worked as expected. This is because the internal coordinate system uses `cm` as the unit length but reports coordinates with unit `pt` when using the coordinate assignment.

Still, I don't understand why the error is "Missing number, treated as zero", but at least I know what is the correct thing to do in the future.